# Caldera Form Advanced File Upload 2 not render in Internet Explorer

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

The Advanced File Upload 2 field from Caldera Forms don't show/render in Internet Explorer 11.

It was rendered in React, and I have only the build files.
There is no error in console so I don't know were to start.

I've tried to insert following polyfill, but nothing changed.

```
 <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same was on Edge.

With the following little Polyfill everything worked fine:

```
 <script>
    (function () {
        if ( typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach === "function" ) return false;
        NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    })();
</script>
```

Found here: https://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/01/06/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-foreach/

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.